# How to fix symbol index entry?

Tags: symbols, indexing

All my entries in the symbol index involving `$\|\cdot\|$` get rejected. For instance
`{\index{symbol}{normx@{$\|\cdot\|_X$}}}`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 8):

The symbol `|` is special within the `\index` command as it deals with special page ranges. You need to hide this from TeX using something like

```
\newcommand{\norm}{\|}
```

Also note that `\index` takes only one argument which is the index entry. If you want to also print this entry in text, you need to use the following format:

```
...blah blah symbol\index{symbol} blah blah...
```

virtually duplicating the typeset component and index entry. Here's your MWE with a the above modifications:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/makeidx
\newcommand{\norm}{\|}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
See $\|\cdot\|_X$\index{normx@$\norm\cdot\norm_X$} and the norm\index{norm}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Consider reading through Leslie Lamport's [MakeIndex : An Index Processor For LaTeX](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/indexing/makeindex/doc/makeindex.pdf).

Answer (score 7):

Special characters for MakeIndex should be *quoted*: so to index `|x|` you have to write

```
\index{"|x"|}
```

The `"` character before a special character makes it lose its meaning. However `\"` is not treated in a particular way (it's an accent command), so your entry should be

```
\index{"\"|x"\"|}
```

or `\index{normx@"\"|x"\"|}` if you want a string for specifying the alphabetic order.

If you use more entries with `|` than entries such as `\index{abc|see def}` you can create a personal MakeIndex style containing just one line

```
encap '*'
```

Call this file `mystyle.ist` and call MakeIndex as

```
makeindex -s mystyle.ist filename
```

This will disable the special feature of `|` (whose role is taken by `*`) and so you can type `\index{normx@$\|x\|$}` without other precautions.