# Norm symbol in subscripts of index

Tags: symbols, indexing

I found this related topic but it didn't seem to fix my problem: [How to fix symbol index entry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57566/how-to-fix-symbol-index-entry/57570#57570)

I was using good old `\|\cdot\|` for norms but my index wasn't liking it.  So then I did the new command `\norm` to be `\|`.  This works great except in subscripts.  To be specific I have something like this:

```
{\index[symbols]{$B_{\norm\cdot\norm}(x,r)$}}
```

And it appears in the index as `$B_{weird stuff}(x,r)$`.  More specifically, going into the index file I see it's recorded as this:

```
$B_{\delimiter 026B30D \cdot \delimiter 026B30D }(x,r)$
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: What happens with `\DeclareRobustCommand*{\norm}{\|}`? (to be used in math mode)

Comment: That fixes it!  Thank you user700902!

Comment: @danzibr: I will make it into an answer so that you can accept it and help me get all the reputation I deserve ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The phenomenon is an instance of `TeX` *"expanding"* things. Sometimes you do not want this to happen: this is discussed in *LaTeX: a document preparation system* under the name of fragile and robust commands. One way to make things "robust" is to use `\DeclareRobustCommand`: so here

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\norm}{\|}
```

can be used to solve your problem.