# Math in section strange PDF output

Tags: math-mode, sectioning

A recently upgraded my computer and on my old PC, this code

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra} 
\usepackage{mathspec}
% Mathfont
\setmathfont{STIXGeneral}
\usepackage[german]{babel} % Neue Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}            % Link to start of figures, not captions

\newcommand{\interpolationOp}[1]{\ensuremath{L_{#1}}}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Der Interpolationsfehler
    \texorpdfstring{\( \|f-\interpolationOp{\mathbf{M}}f\| \)}{||f- IMf||} 
    }
\end{document}
```

Would produce both a correct PDF-Meta-TOC and a correct TOC using XeLaTeX.

However, now the TOC looks like this

[image: Faulty TOC]

Deleting either mathspec or the babel packes removes the faulty TOC, but I need both packages. Further, the `.aux` file states

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {0.1}Der Interpolationsfehler \( \delimiter "026B30D f-\ensuremath  {L_{\mathbf  {M}}}f\delimiter "026B30D  \)}{1}{section.0.1}}
```

Which looks like `TeX`is expanding (but somehow just since I changed my computer) the `\|`, though the hint from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99854/norm-symbol-in-subscripts-of-index), declaring a robust command would not work.

Any ideas, why this is introduced in my new setup (though i can't say what the difference is, the old PC is not available atm, maybe a difference between MacTex 2013 and 2012)?

Comment: Just a comment unrelated to your question, but regarding your code example: As mentioned in [another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67549/whats-the-difference-between-ngerman-and-german-in-babel), you need to use `ngerman` instead of `german` for the new German orthography.

Comment: And one further interesting point would be: Why did that work on my previous (MacTex 2012) system?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `\|` is expanded into

```
\delimiter "026B30D
```

in the `.toc` file and the quotes disturb XeLaTeX when `mathspec` is loaded.

Solution: add

```
\protected\def\|{\Vert}
```

to your preamble. However the problem would be the same if you use `\Vert` in a section title (don't do it!)

Don't load `xunicode` and `xltxtra`. Documentation saying they are needed is outdated.

I wouldn't use `mathspec`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} % or any other Times-like font
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\usepackage[german]{babel} % Neue Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}            % Link to start of figures, not captions

\newcommand{\interpolationOp}[1]{\ensuremath{L_{#1}}}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Der Interpolationsfehler
    \texorpdfstring{\( \|f-\interpolationOp{\mathbf{M}}f\| \)}{||f- IMf||}
    }
\end{document}
```

I wouldn't use `\ensuremath` in the definition of `\interpolationOp` either.

Comment: What should I then load in XeLaTeX to ensure utf8 despite those two packages? The point is, that the project is nearly finished and the first (faulty) PDF endet up being at the publisher, so i don't want to change too much (in order to not have to resubmit everything)...

What should I use instead of `mathspec` - `unicode-math`?

And finally: I always thought `\ensuremath` was to ensure, that the command is only used in `math` - so what would you use instead?

Comment: Oh, and - is `XITS Math` the same font as `STIXGeneral`?

Comment: @Ronny Yes, but with the math tables added

Comment: I'll use your very hopeful tips on my next project :) But for this one, I fear, If I now (at this late stage) change something (well I already hat to change my computer, you saw, what that did), that might be uncomfortable for me.

Answer (score 2):

So one dirty and quite local way (because it just affects this and onyl this `\section`) would be to

```
\texorpdfstring{\( {\protect\|}f-\interpolationOp{\mat{M}}f{\protect\|}\)}{||f- LMf||}
```

in order to not get them expanded.
Edit: But of course, that should either be used in a command or - even better - use @egreg s remarks in his answer.