# Using || inside latex nomenclature

Tags: symbols, nomenclature

I wanted to write `|a|` in nomenclature symbol as well as in the description.

But whenever I use `|` in any particular nomenclature entry, that entry disappears from nomenclature list altogether. There is no error, and the rest of the nomenclature prints fine.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please provide a complete MWE from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: Use `\lvert a\rvert` (requires `amsmath`) or `"|a"|`, because `|` is a special character for MakeIndex. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57566/how-to-fix-symbol-index-entry

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Your solution works perfectly.